# how to properly navigate through authentication views in vaadin 7

Tags: java, exception, vaadin, navigator

I am trying to navigate from my login view to another view ... this process is via a authentication method I wrote. I am able to get from the login view to the other, however, when I refresh the window I get an ugly exception that is telling me there is no such view I want to access. I tried already to have 2 UIs. One for login and the other for everything else, in the first one I wanted to set the other UI via `setContent()` method but I gave me even more ugly exception, and then I found out it is forbidden or something like that so I tried it again with views and navigator but failed. Could you please help me? The code from my ui that sets the navigator goes..

```
navigator = new Navigator(this, this);

navigator.addView("",new LoginView());
```

In the authentication method I call:

```
getUI().getNavigator().addView("kniznica", new LoggedInView());
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("kniznica");
```

to add a new view to the ui and then to navigate to it.

the exception after I refresh the view referred to as 'kniznica':

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to navigate to an unknown state 'kniznica' and an error view provider not present
at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:525)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:534)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.getBrowserDetailsUI(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2468)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleBrowserDetailsRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:2362)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:325)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is not navigating to the Login View first. Try this:

```
public static String LOGINVIEW ="LoginView";
public static String LOGGEDINVIEW = "kniznica";

navigator = new Navigator(this, this);

navigator.addView(LOGINVIEW ,new LoginView());
navigator.navigateTo(LOGINVIEW );
```

In the authentication method call:

```
getUI().getNavigator().addView(LOGGEDINVIEW, new LoggedInView());
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(LOGGEDINVIEW);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did already find something useful here:[https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20simple%20login%20view](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20simple%20login%20view)

Answer (score 0):

use the following in your UI class, at the end of init method:

```
this.navigator.setErrorView(myView);
```

and it will be fixed the error with the empty fragment.